# Maxima use with php

Tags: php

I try to use function like shell_exec() or system() to execute maxima scripts with php. Example:

```
<?php
chdir("C:\Program Files (x86)\Maxima-sbcl-5.35.1.2\bin");
$cmd = "maxima";
$res = exec($cmd,$out,$status);
echo "out=";
print_r($out);
echo "res=".$res.PHP_EOL;
echo "status=".$status.PHP_EOL;`
?>
```

Output:

```
out=Array
(
    [0] => Maxima 5.35.1.2 http://maxima.sourceforge.net
    [1] => using Lisp SBCL 1.2.7
    [2] => Distributed under the GNU Public License. See the file COPYING.
    [3] => Dedicated to the memory of William Schelter.
    [4] => The function bug_report() provides bug reporting information.
    [5] => (%i1)
)
res=(%i1)
status=0
```

In Match "(%i1)_" I have to run script like "solve(x^2-1=0, x)";

But it's not recognized like a cmd script.

Comment: [link] http://andrejv.github.io/wxmaxima/

Answer (score 1):

You’re currently trying to run Maxima in *interactive* mode, i.e. like you would start the command from a shell and interactively enter expressions and get their results in return.

What you need is *non-interactive* mode. According to Maxima’s [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/maxima.1L.html), there are generally two ways to work in non-interactive mode: `--batch` and `--batch-string` (also, `--batch-lisp`, but that’s not relevant here).

The first method expects you to pass a file name with the expressions to be processed. The second method allows to define a string from the command line.

In your example, you should invoke Maxima like the following:

```
$expr = escapeshellarg("solve(x^2-1=0, x)");
$cmd = "maxima --batch-string=$expr";
// … and so on
```

If you want to do more complex calculations, you should dump them to a temporary file and pass the file location to Maxima via the `--batch` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the command string in a file to Maxima, that is supported by command-line Maxima.

if your OS is `Linux/Unix/MacOS`:

In PHP:

```
exec('maxima -q -b file');
```

for example, this file can be **input.txt**, the content inside this file is `solve(x^2-1=0, x);stringout("result.txt", %o2);quit();`

or

```
system('maxima -q -b file');
```

if your OS is `Win`:

```
$maximaDir = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Maxima-sbcl-5.35.1.2'; // If your maxima is installed in elsewhere, please modified this location

exec($maximaDir.'/bin/maxima.bat -q -b "input.txt"');
```

In Maxima, you can use `stringout();` to get the result in a file, then in PHP read the file as a string, you can do any other manipulations to the string as you want.